# TOleServer and its unit not available for Firemonkey in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, ole

I can't find that unit. Is there an equivalent?

I am trying to port a unit from VCL to Firemonkey which contains `OleServer` in its `uses` clause, but I can't find any information on Embarcaderos website regarding this problem.

Where can I find `TOleServer` and/or its unit `OleServer` that is compatible with Firemonkey?

Or how can I implement that unit in my Firemonkey project?

Comment: Keep in mind that FMX is mainly targeted at cross platform development. OLE is a ms windows technology, so it is no surprise you can't do OLE in Firemonkey.

Comment: What you need to do is work out why this unit is being used? Which COM server is being used?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it is being used in a set of components which handles Windows Portable Devices, and the components are available in VCL app but not in Firemonkey app. And it doesnt say anything about which COM server is being used, only that the components ancestor is TOleServer

Comment: Do you know what the code is doing? All the same, it doesn't sound like it's very easy to consume com servers from fmx if you are compelled to haul in vcl. I might be tempted to use a modified OleServer unit that doesn't use vcl.

Comment: Why use Firemonkey if you're targeting Windows?

Comment: @JerryDodge I'm working on a multiplatform app, but depending on the target OS it different parts of code will be executed using compiler directives. Right now I'm working on the Windows code. Also Firemonkey provides good GUI framework for animations and such.

Comment: A lot of the unit names have changed from before. If you use the "Find in Files" window in Delphi to search the source code, you will see that TOleServer is in VCL.OleServer.pas. Usually you can use non-visual Windows units in Firemonkey in a Windows application. Of course, there is no such thing as COM OLE in OSX.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before and I made a change in OleServer:

1. Copy `Vcl.OleSever` to your project and rename it to `FMX.OleServer`
2. in implementation section do change like this:

   ```
   implementation
   uses
     FMX.Controls;

   resourcestring
     sNoRunningObject = 'Unable to retrieve a pointer to a running object registered with OLE for %s/%s';
   ```
3. at the initialization section change to `FMX.Controls.TControl`

   ```
   initialization
     GroupDescendentsWith(TOleServer, FMX.Controls.TControl);
   end.
   ```
4. Finally rename `VCL.OleServer` to `FMX.OleServer` in your imported library unit

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the main issue with compiling TLB (typelibrary) units for COM/OLE Servers seems to be some unit renaming that has occured. Ideally the Delphi IDE should detect this automatically and fix it.

Based on Doug Rudd's comment above I fixed my "uses OleServer" to "uses Vcl.OleServer" in my TLB unit.

Since there's a "source" folder under Delphi installation folder even for the Pro version now (at least at 10.2.2 Tokyo version that I'm currently using), I could also easily spot (using GrepWin free tool) where the "EmptyParam" that was causing my TLB to not compile had gone. It is under System.Variants unit that one also needs to use in their TLB (before it was in System so you didn't need to use some unit for it).

Guess I could have imported the COM/OLE Server again to make new TLB import unit, but since it was hand-ended (to remove using of "Graphics", "StdVcl" and "OleCtrls" units that were bloating the executable size in older versions of Delphi) and that hand-edited imported TLB used to work fine for a command-line application, I didn't have any reason to reimport the Type Library.

You can see the changes I did to make my XSLer tool work with the latest Delphi at https://github.com/Zoomicon/tranXform/commit/e99f42049b8a4c1534d9edb78ed5e6493e6e5786. That XSLer command-line tool is using MSXML (Microsoft XML) automation server.